# Диаграмма ганта (попадание отрезков времени)

Tags: php

В базе данных  есть 3 поля с датами. Это значит 3 отрезка. До х1, от х1 до х2, от х2 до х2+х дней. И отрезок участка самой диаграммы - обычно это  24 часа, т.е. у1 и  у1+ 23:59:59, где у1, например, 10.03.12. Работаю со временем в формате юникса, т.е секундах.

Сама сложность вывести из базы данных именно поля, попадающие в условия данного графика. Например:

> `10.03.12 00:00|---------------------------------------------|10.03.12 23:59:59`

А в базе данные

> `05.03.12 10:00,  10.03.12 12:00,  10.03.12 11:00`

т.е наш отрезок времени попадает в диапазон. Центральную дату брать нет смысла, а только крайние части диапазона.

Как задать условие вывода?  Тут фактически пару сравнений, но нужно, чтоб даже если 1 час попадает, то выводить. Или полдиапазона, например:

> `10.03.12 00:00|---------------------------------------------|10.03.12 23:59:59`

А в базе  данные

> `10.03.12 23:00,  12.03.12 12:00,  15.03.12 11:00`

т.е. первая дата на час, но попадает в наш график.

P.S. Начало и конец отрезка учитывать тоже надо, т.к график может быть как на день, так и на неделю, и вывести придется данные, которые хоть краем попадают в график, например:

> `10.03.12 00:00|---------------------------------------------|17.03.12 23:59:59`

А в базе  данные

> `11.03.12 10:00,  12.03.12 12:00,  13.03.12 11:00`

Тут полностью попали, но могли только час графика в начале или час в конце.

Сама функция отрисовки графика цветами есть и выводит с шагом в час.

Comment: Можете попорядку соотнести xN с соответствующими полями, объяснить, чему равен x. тогда, возможно, вам помогут скорее

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что у тебя там за бд, но в mysql есть такая штука как интервал, для работы с датой ей спокойно можно воспользоватся, типа

```
SELECT INTERVAL 1 DAY + "1997-12-31";
```

или если рассчитывать просто на цифры то можно так

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > 1 AND id < 5
```

Comment: >Не знаю что у тебя там за бд, но в mysql есть такая штука как интервал, для >работы с датой ей спокойно можно воспользоватся, типа
 Мне удобнее работать с юникс временем т.к в самом скрипте еще происходит перевод часовых поясов и т.д

>или если рассчитывать просто на цифры то можно так
 Вот, мне как раз и нужна формула(как вы показали не подойдет  т.к у меня используется 4 времени (2 отрезка их начало и концы).  Как показали вы я пробовал в разных вариантах, но очень много моментов когда выпадают интервалы. На бумаге моделировал с простыми числами( Голова кипит. Поэтому и обратился за помощь